# WKInterfaceTable not loading values

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I'm loading interfacetable values from context send from iOS application. The data passing was successful but the tableview method

```
rowController(at: index)
```

Is returning nil 
Value and numberOfRows variable was still 0 after line of code

```
tableView.setNumberOfRows(3, withRowType: "deviceRow")
```

My overall code is

```
func setupTable() {
    tableView.setNumberOfRows(devicesArray.count, withRowType: "deviceRow2")

    for (index, device) in self.devicesArray.enumerated() {
        if let row = tableView.rowController(at: index) as? MeasurementCell {

            row.deviceNameLabel.setText(device)
            row.readingLabel.setText(self.readingsArray[index])
            let statusColor = colorWithHexString(hex: self.colorsArray[index])
            // row.backgroundGroupView.setBackgroundColor(statusColor.withAlphaComponent(0.2))
            row.readingLabel.setTextColor(statusColor)
            row.dateLabel.setText(self.datesArray[index])
            row.readingLabel.setTextColor(self.getColor(fromString: self.colorsArray[index]))
            row.readingLabel.sizeToFitWidth()
        }
    }
```

Is there any workaround for the issue? Suggestions are highly appriciated.

Comment: Only logical way where numberOfRows is 0, even if you explicitly set it to 3 is that tableView is nil

Answer (score 1):

In Identity inspector of interfaceController

It was

[image]

When I changed the same as shown below, **it worked by apple magic**.
[image]

Don't know reason behind how does this fix worked. Hope anyone in future may help this answer.